# sscanf - reading from empty string

Tags: c, io, scanf, string

When I pass an empty string to `sscanf`, it returns zero and it doesn't change the given variable.

```
char* ptr = "";
abc = sscanf(ptr, "%s", output);
// abc == 0
```

Can you let me know the way to work it out?

Comment: Post *real* C code which can be compilable with what output you were expecting.

Comment: null is 0.  You expected null and got it.

Comment: He said he expects NULL to be assigned to `output` I guess. 0 is the return value of `sscanf`.

Answer (score 6):

[`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) awaits the first argument to be the *C string that the function processes as its source to retrieve the data*. Passing an empty string to this function can't yield your variable to be initialized, since there is nothing this function would initialize it with.

Also note that *On success, the function returns the number of variables filled. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens. In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.*

Following code, compiled with MinGW (gcc-core 4.5.0-1)

```
char str[10];
int ret = sscanf("", "%9s", str);
printf("%d\n", ret);
```

outputs `-1` (EOF)

Good way of checking whether `sscanf` was successful is to check whether it's return value is really equal to the number of provided variables. In this case it would be `if (ret == 1)`. Although many people just check, whether value greater than 0 was returned, to make sure that something has been read and that no error has occurred.